# Augmenting unknown types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm dealing with Gutenberg blocks in a headless fashion. A Gutenberg block can be represented with the following type:

```tsx
type Block = {
    name: string;
    className?: string;
    key?: string | number;
    clientId: string;
    innerBlocks: Block[];
    attributes: Record< string, unknown >;
    style?: Record< string, unknown >;
};
```

Now, for each block, my intention was to type the `attributes` such as:

```tsx
type MyBlockProps = Block & {
  attributes: {
    title: string;
  };
};

function MyBlock( { attributes: { title } }: MyBlockProps ) {
  return <h1>{title}</h1>;
}
```

However, when it comes to rendering all blocks it's where the problem begins. See this renderer

```tsx
function BlockRenderer( { blocks } : { blocks: Block[] } ) {
  return blocks.map( ( { attributes, clientId, innerBlocks, name }, index ) => {
            const key = clientId || index;
            const props: Block = {
                name,
                key,
                clientId,
                attributes,
                innerBlocks,        
            };

            switch ( name ) {
                case 'block/my-block':
                    return <MyBlock { ...props } />;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        } )
        .filter( ( block ) => block );
}
```

The `<MyBlock` part gets an error like this

```
Type '{ name?: string | undefined; className?: string | undefined; key?: string | number | undefined; clientId: string; innerBlocks: Block[]; attributes: Record<string, unknown>; style?: Record<...> | undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ attributes: { title: string; }; }'.
  Types of property 'attributes' are incompatible.
    Property 'title' is missing in type 'Record<string, unknown>' but required in type '{ title: string; }'
```

I have prepared a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwtgK4DOSyAZnAL5xVQQhwDkUqGrAUNzAJ5gkcAEIAbCGgDWcALy5uASAB2KEEgD8ALjhkYUYMoDmAbiVoxKMmQByazTr0HjZxVKT9tu-YaNwAPnDKJCAARkhQrhbASMowAJIAJo4%20LkqGyhHiklJkOtnSANoAuq4oMD6hJDBIeYhIaNCJADzezkakylLKEADuynAAfK56-GIO9Y1QLW2%20nd19A8PctGZ8gsIAsvwFUgAKTGBkcqIS0nAAZApwcOWV1bU6ONw3NzDAMOMp7WY3qytrbhUEjKDDACADba7AAUuFuFQMVRqdTw70%20wnotB0ULO%200OxwAlNc4BwYCQoANmgALACMgxwaPGtGaAHpactaLxgaD3hDTjlkMpEhEIrC8KFccd6E84BKcnVdiU6HAic8bqTyQM5dIyAA6EAoMCwsXw%207I7DRWIJRLYDJZSXYVTqOi2oVIAAeKrkgwUij9jWUejg7n4J0tcSSAUChmF7tc-ohQbA%20PyuJOzz9fqdSEwSkzIdzmcU4ethczd0RDzIZb9dqgu2rfrzin%20zbIvQ%20aCpcFh2a9GczaCswlY2qkLJA-AAtGPWFpm36NRS4M0cTk4brN8mIEdlSzlkXhVQUCQxDB50XFEuBsExGJ4y28-QCXndVRgGfRT3ZWmibIfWOKpmJy3BAA) with this exact code to showcase the issue. How can I deal with this?
Obviously, this is meant to scale and have more blocks but this is a minimal reproducible case.

---

Edit: I understand it can be done by exporting types of MyBlockProps and casting when spreading but I'm wondering if there's a better way

Comment: You can use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to validate the required additional attributes ([example](https://tsplay.dev/W4bQXN)). Does that answer your question? If so, I can write it up as one — if not, what did I miss?

Comment: @jsejcksn I don't know if it answers it since I'm not that skilled in TypeScript, if you can make my playground work with that then it should just work?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75992443/augmenting-unknown-types?noredirect=1#comment134029764_75992443) That is your code: I copied it from your question and linked you to a modified playground that I created.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75992443/augmenting-unknown-types/75993194#comment134029764_75992443) If you're asking about what a _type guard_ is, you can read the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) and check out the many other questions/answers on this site that have covered that topic: [SO query for `[typescript] type guard`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5btypescript%5d%20type%20guard) — it's better not to duplicate content on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) function to validate the required additional attributes — if the block object passes the validation, the compiler will know that the expected attributes are present.

Here's a complete example based on the information presented in your question:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzjAnmApnASughgYxgFEAbdEdAO3gF84AzKCEOAIij0NYG4AoX1BjgAhEhHwBrOAF5EvOHEq4KALjgBnGFGCUA5nwX4SudeoByy9AH41m7XoNwJ6FDY1aduuAB9FAVxAAI3QoRyNgKhgASQATWw8HeTgdShDRcQl1NXTJAG0AXUdcGA9Avxh0LOx0fGgYgB47TwAaOD9KCUoIAHdKAD5HTRQyNxxaqAamvVb2zp7+vho+ATRMAFkUHIkABSYwdRkRMUk4ADI5BWLS8sq1BCSFGGAYMnj7fSSl3i-eenbCYAQShwDZbAAUSCu2jKFSqSCeL0wdBoalBxx2e3UAEo1DgCMQyBRqBc4BwYH4oMD6gALACMfQQCLINHqAHo6QNvvxWQAqHlwAACZIplAOAAMtH50GLkvRkNTMAA3XAkKXJA5deBiyh+EgkGXQOBi9oxdD0HToGIynms37-J5AxRAsy64yBMj1AAqfTBytV6DUnpxcD9auABzMztduHd6C9fRJwspIZVaoAhLIdXrFty+YKk6KjZLpbL5UrU5h1MVw+bKmXSegAI5+YAcIkwA42u2UAGO90ZAASJhwzdbloAgiVoTd1F64OgAB4VSgxA5bH39ySB4ObqThuCes4gzbo3YQfaJ9Dk5Ngh5wVmsuAANRVwBixUwHFHHBicChwBhW470EdAIDlXcADp-0A9QIKZTBpEQtgpl0Vg7wfOBxzEPQ4G6Z5qT-SgUDgCAYAVKA-ynACZ3lYo4BQCA-DgEBgF0al4FwGJfxgCBjy2M99hUdDH1Oc4QLAuBIOgmcIPUZh0AAeTIkJJ2uCoZCQ1gdSCEI0IULEc27XtgS2HAVxCEIIUk9EDhRRBrIyKotgKOAaGDPFCFIchIhc+4FALBzJFgkBcDAMErOk2FWnCSJYlaFI0hs1olAoVz4vMhcsRkBM-IUOBalFeBnGI2QYuoWIfF8HRTQXRxDCBTQ4DATFsnRQ5cryxRLGaO8FGKnrOsMEgInKmIBsGyLKnGzqEqgLZ1Gm1zlk69Q8JgfACLBFL0Cyjq8vwExMAAcl3VkQBQABaXcjruXq8uAOUwV3Id1BHFsf1U6dYTBZrz2xXa7s6gL6jRDJEAgiHfv2OhWU5Qa8rodASHUTA9vhjChxXMh61I8j8sOuByMwMFDRiIEjpgLFAdcu6aDu016FwXUYDUAKsxIOqaYUNyIPNEgKigLaoz1GMyAMrkgA)

```ts
import { type ReactElement } from "react";

type Block = {
  name: string;
  className?: string;
  key?: string | number;
  clientId: string;
  innerBlocks: Block[];
  attributes: Record<string, unknown>;
  style?: Record<string, unknown>;
};

type MyBlockProps = Block & {
  attributes: {
    title: string;
  };
};

function MyBlock({ attributes: { title } }: MyBlockProps): ReactElement {
  return <h1>{title}</h1>;
}

/** @returns `true` if the value is not `null` or `undefined` */
function nonNullable<T>(value: T): value is NonNullable<T> {
  return value != null;
}

/** @returns `true` if the value satisfies the requirements */
function blockHasRequiredAttributes<T extends Block>(block: T): block is T & MyBlockProps {
  return (
    // Validate required attributes:
    typeof block.attributes.title === "string"
    // Along with any other attributes that you might add to MyBlockProps:
    // && typeof block.attributes.someOtherAttribute === "number"
  );
}

function BlockRenderer({ blocks }: { blocks: Block[] }): ReactElement[] {
  return blocks.map(({ attributes, clientId, innerBlocks, name }, index) => {
    const key = clientId || index;
    const props: Block = {
      name,
      key,
      clientId,
      attributes,
      innerBlocks,
    };

    switch (name) {
      case 'block/my-block': {
        if (blockHasRequiredAttributes(props)) {
          return <MyBlock {...props} />;
        } else {
          // Handle the other case here (or don't)
        }
      }
      default: return null;
    }
  }).filter(nonNullable);
}
```